# Switching between console and GUI in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, lightdm, gui, tty

When in GUI mode, is there a CLI commands that kills the GUI and drops me into the console?

When in CLI mode, is there a CLI command that drops me into the GUI?

I found `startx`, but this drop me into the GUI without the unity interface, how do I launch anything?

I found `service lightdm start` which drops me into the GUI with the unity interface.

I found `service lightdm stop` which drops me into a blank black screen with no CLI input capability.

I found the <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F*</kbd> sends me back between console and GUI, but it does not kill the GUI. I want to kill the GUI if I don't want to use it anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go in tty1 and stop the GUI, run from terminal:

```
sudo xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+F1 && sudo service lightdm stop
```

You can test now in the tty1 the fact that the GUI is stopped using:

```
sudo service lightdm status
```

Note: `xdotool` is not installed by default in Ubuntu, so you must to install it first using `sudo apt-get install xdotool` command.

To start the GUI again from tty1, you can run (as you said):

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

If you want also to close (exit) tty1 session, you can use:

```
sudo service lightdm start && logout
```

Answer (score 4):

Since 16.04 (and possibly 15.10, but I skipped everything between 14.04 and 16.04...), you are expected to use `systemctl` instead:

To start `lightdm`, you will get the `lightdm` prompt (login screen) first:

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
```

Then to leave X-Windows start `multi-user` instead:

```
sudo chvt 1 && sudo systemctl start multi-user.target
```

`chvt` means "Change Virtual Terminal", because otherwise you get on vt 7 which will look like something is broken. You can use the Alt-F1 to Alt-F7 or even Alt-F8 to switch between terminals.

For more information about systemd, check out the [systemd wiki](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). I am still learning myself!

---

The `graphical.target` file is found under `/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target` and looks like this (16.04 version):

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Graphical Interface
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=display-manager.service
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=multi-user.target rescue.service rescue.target display-manager.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

The `multi-user.target` file is found under `/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target` and looks like this (16.04 version):

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Multi-User System
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what `graphical.target` and `multi-user.target` is and how these targets are specified, and where they are specified.