# Ubuntu 18.04 booting to terminal in VirtualBox

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my virtual machine. It worked fine in the morning, probably at evening the VirtualBox image is loading to terminal. I Googled the problem and tried all the solutions I found but none of them worked.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between console and GUI in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435314/switching-between-console-and-gui-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu server or desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)